# R: Removing the "Chapter" part from the title in bookdown::pdf_book with documentclass: report

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown

consider my header and first section

```
---
title: "asdf"
author: "asdf"
date: "13 Januar 2018"
documentclass: report
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    citation_package: biblatex
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    number_sections: yes
    fig_caption: yes
---

# Introduction
Here begins my introduction
```

I want to remove the automatic "Chapter 1" part, thats sits in front of the actual chapter title (in this case **Introduction**) 
This does not work

```
header-includes:
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
```

Also using another documentclass does not work, because I need the number of my sections/chapters be represented in the figure captions (e.g Figure 3.1)
What I would like is to end up with a Title **1 Introduction** , than **2 Methods** and so on.
Should not be to hard, but I can't figure it out.
Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
subparagraph: true
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
```

together with

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
```

in `preamble.tex` (c.f. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/how-to-set-the-chapter-style-in-report-class). You have to make sure that the LaTeX package [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) is installed in your TeX system.

At the time of writing `subparagraph: true` was needed since the used pandoc LaTeX template redefined `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` in a way interfering with `titlesec`. This has changed since then. at least with `rmarkdown` version 2.1 one no longer needs `subparagraph: true`. thanks @MarkNeal for noticing this!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still got an error message. But after including   "subparagraph: true" in the header it worked! Maybe you can update your answer, so I can mark it accepted. I also had to download titlesec with the MiKTeX Package Manager, maybe you can update this too.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! However I tried to use the answer presented here, I get the following error message: Error: YAML output format must evaluate to a function
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(input, encoding = "UTF-8") :
  incomplete final line found on '_output.yml'

The yaml header looks like this: 
subparagraph: true
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default

Comment: @Haakonkas YAML headers are quite picky when it comes to formatting, but that gets lost in a comment. Please create a new question.

Comment: @MarkNeal Thanks! It seems like the used LaTeX template has improved over time!